# Multiple views/table in different events - #C

Tags: c#, forms

*Project purpose: user should login and be able to create/remove/edit/search log*
- C# Forms

The main view is displayed after identified user in DB and access is given.
There's 5 buttons in main view, (create log) (remove log) (search log) (edit log) (log out) For instance:

If user press (create log), a table? should be displayed where user can write log that will be written to DB.

If user press (search log), a table? should be displayed where user can search log from DB. etc...

*Summarize: all of the menu selection should be displayed, wether user choose create, search etc..*

What's the best and easiest way to manage this? Any idea of what I should begin with? Im stuck... Been Reading about fill/hide..

First code below is placed in **form.cs**, when user has filled out two textboxes (username, password) and press login, this code will execute:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            ProjectFunc loginF = new ProjectFunc();  
            loginF.GetId(username, password);  

            if(loginF.UserId == 0)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username and/or password, try again."); 
            }        

            else 
            { 
                this.Hide();  
            } 
            username_txt.Clear(); 
            password_txt.Clear(); 

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to DB" + ex);
        }
```

The functions is placed in another file **program.cs**

```
 class ProjectFunc
 {

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return userid; }
        set { userid = value; }
    }
    public void GetId(string username, string password) 
    { 
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(myCon)) 
        { 
            con.Open(); 
            using (var cmd =new SqlCommand("Select userid from Login, UserLogin where Login.loginid   = UserLogin.loginid and username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "' ;", con);   
            { 
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
                { 
                    while (reader.Read()) 
                    {                             
                        userId = (int)reader[0];                             
                        Main menu = new Main(); 
                        menu.Show(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

    }  
 }
```

This is **main.cs**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } // 5 buttons totally, nothing else so far.
```

**DB Table**

Table Login: (PK loginid), username, password

Table UserLogin: (FK userid, loginid)

Table User: (PK userid), firstname, lastname, personid

Table Guestbook: (PK gbid), date, name, title, text

Comment: Did you look at `DataGridView`?

Comment: Which DB should be used? How do you want to access it (directly, EF, Dapper, ...)? Do you already have a model?

Comment: Haven't looked at DataGridView yet. Could it be a solution?
I use Sql Express and it's working fine. Yes sir.

Comment: If you have a model please let us know about it. What data should the user insert/update? DataGridView can visualize and let the user edit one DB table. That includes adding, updating and deleting rows. You will need to write the logic that applies the changes back to the db.

Comment: When you write `log` in the question do you mean `login`? In your model there's nothing about `log`s. You need to write your question more specific because nobody can guess what you want to know based on the given information. We can't give you a starting point if you don't ask a specific question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my Sql Query for login. User will declared as userid 1 or 2, depending on which user that is logged on. That is, return value 1 or 2, because I have two users.
My main question was how I'm able to use one form(interface) with several menu selections. All buttons should be visible either choose create log or search log, just the content in these selections that should be switched. However, found out that listtabel were the answer.

Comment: Then please post the answer you found and post it, so that pepole looking for the same problem as you did find your answer.